# How to use angular dart components material shadow and typography?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

How to apply elevation style to my headline in the angular dart project?

app_component.html

```
<div class="welcome">
    <h1 class="headline">Demo Headline</h1>
</div>
```

app_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

:host {

}
.headline {        

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [tree demo](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components_example/tree/master/lib/src/material_tree_demo) shows how to apply elevation.

**CSS**

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/shadow';

.shadow {
  @include shadow-elevation(16);

  width: 400px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="shadow">
```

**Typography**

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

.headline {
  @include mat-font-headline;
}
```